# What guarantees are there about the Windows Azure runtime components?

Tags: deployment, azure, components

What's the minimal guaranteed list of functionality a Windows Azure instance will provide?

For example, I want to use Powershell from inside my Azure role. Currently all Windows Azure instances do have Powershell. What if Microsoft suddenly decides to stop deploying Powershell by default?

Is there a list of guaranteed components and functionality that I may assume unconditionally available inside Windows Azure instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee with respect to features currently available in Windows Azure.  Obviously, Microsoft being the late-comer to the cloud game and an underdog, will not likely be cutting features out but only adding features in, but there is certainly no guarantee.
We do know that Azure instances are running Win2008 and you can lock them down to a certain version of a patch so that nothing is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting post, not sure if MSFT have a complete list of what's on offer (I do remember this being talked about in the early days when it went to general release), be nice to see a list. (*cough mark russinovich!)

Re: Powershell, its not going anywhere fast, its a core tenant of the Windows o/s and I could bet my house on it.

Startup tasks are your ideal preference to ensure you have what you need in Azure, for instance I install the Java JVM on the box (VM role) during a startup task, it's not there naively but it is when my code runs!

http://www.davidaiken.com/2011/01/19/running-azure-startup-tasks-as-a-real-user/